# selecting image from gallery for the second time does no work and show a black screen

Tags: android, performance, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

1) Select image from gallery and image view will be updated with the picture;

2) For the first attempt, it actually works, the picture I took is displayed properly.

3) I launch the gallery again and select picture, the app goes into a blank screen and nothing happens.

I've been logging my trace and for the second time, onActivityResult is not even called despite startActivityForResult() being called already.

Here's some snippets of the relevant code:

```
private ImageView groupImage;
private Uri selectedImage;
groupImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.groupLogo);
groupImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }
    });

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
try{
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null){
         selectedImage = data.getData();

        groupImage.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage));

    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.getStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: and some time i receive this java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed

Comment: actually ironman the exception is not generated becz app is not getting the try block

Comment: You should move your super call to the end of `onActivityResult` and only have it called if you don't consume the result yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes a trouble:

```
groupImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.groupLogo);
```

In the `onActivityResult` function you override a previous reference to the `groupImage`, therefore on `onClickListener` is not assigned to your `ImageView`